# Trigger Events on Same Level of DOM with Triggered Event

Tags: javascript, events

I was learning about bubbling and capturing and although this situation does not apply to either case, I wanted to know if there is a way to do it with the event handling in JS. The problem:

Here I make a few boxes and a trigger on the same level of the DOM. I provide an event listener to each for a custom event(avalanche) that can be triggered on clicking the bottom box. I want the trigger to be emitted to the other elements changing their background color. See code below.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <script src="./actions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="one block"></div>
    <div class="two block"></div>
    <div class="three block"></div>

    <div class="four trigger"> Fire When Ready </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.block, .trigger{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.one{
    background-color: red;
}

.two{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.three{
    background-color: green;
}

.four{
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

JS

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    console.log("content loaded");

    var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("block");

    for(var i = 0; i<blocks.length; i++){
        (function(){
            var target = blocks[i];

            target.addEventListener("avalanche", function(){
                this.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            }, true);
        })()
    }

    var beacon = document.getElementsByClassName("four")[0]; 
    beacon.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("fired!");
        // trigger the event and watch the cascade 
        beacon.dispatchEvent(cascade); 
    });

    // create a custom event 
    var cascade = new CustomEvent('avalanche', {});

    console.log("handlers set");
});
```

So, the idea would be to click the bottom box and have the event launch and be seen by the other divs in the body. These divs would all be triggered to change the background color of the boxes. Can this be done? There are obvious other ways to do this with JS but I wanted to do it by listening for the avalanche event.

Answer (score 0):

The dispatch needs to be run on the target elements (*see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent*) and not on the beacon, so you will need to iterate over the matching elements (*the siblings in this case*).

```js
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    console.log("content loaded");

    var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("block");

    for(var i = 0; i<blocks.length; i++){
        (function(){
            var target = blocks[i];

            target.addEventListener("avalanche", function(){
                this.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            }, true);
        })()
    }

    var beacon = document.getElementsByClassName("four")[0]; 
    beacon.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("fired!");
        // trigger the event and watch the cascade 
        var sameLevel = beacon.parentNode.children; // get siblings (and self)
        Array.from(sameLevel).forEach(function(node){
          node.dispatchEvent(cascade)
        });
    });

    // create a custom event 
    var cascade = new CustomEvent('avalanche', {});

    console.log("handlers set");
});
```

```css
.block, .trigger{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.one{
    background-color: red;
}

.two{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.three{
    background-color: green;
}

.four{
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <script src="./actions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="one block"></div>
    <div class="two block"></div>
    <div class="three block"></div>

    <div class="four trigger"> Fire When Ready </div>

</body>
</html>
```